# Javascript: Displaying images with check boxes values

Tags: javascript

I am currently working with radio buttons and check boxes to display images with the help of javascript. To be specific: I am running into an issue when working check boxes and displaying the images. With the radio buttons only one image will be display for that category. But with checkboxes more than one image need to be display. For example, a user can check field for jacket and glove and both pictures will be display.

How can I format the function to display multiple pictures when check boxes are clicked?  [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/bike_calculator/)

**JS**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function check_value(val, id, type) {     
    var el = document.getElementById("imgBox" + id);
    if (val>0 && val<4) { //will trigger when [1,2,3]
       el.src = "images/"+ type + val + ".jpg";
       el.style.display = "";
  }    
  }      

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Choose a bike</h2>
<form name="builder">
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(1, 1, "bike")'/> KAWASAKI KX 450F<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(2, 1, "bike")'/> 2010 Yamaha Road Star S<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(3, 1, "bike")'/> Aprilia RSV4<br />
</form>

<img id="imgBox1" src="#" style="display:none"> 

<h2>Choose a tire</h2>  
<form name="tire">
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(1, 2, "tire")'/> Michelin Pilot Road 3 Tires<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(2, 2, "tire")'/> Dunlop Roadsmart Sport-Touring Tires<br />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(3, 2, "tire")'/> Pirelli Scorpion Trail Tires<br />
</form>

<img id="imgBox2" src="#" style="display:none">

<h2>Choose Accesories</h2>
<form name="tire">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(1, 3, "accesories")'/> Chrome Front Plate<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(2, 3, "accesories")'/> Jacket<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(3, 3, "accesories")'/> Gloves            
</form>

<img id="imgBox3" src="#" style="display:none">
```

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: You should use `label` elements and associate them via `for` attribute to the input with the same `id`. See relevant [WCAG 2.0 H44 Technique](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44). Users will then be able to click on the large area made by the label more easily than on tiny checkboxes and radio (and it won't be inaccessible anymore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two more image boxes:

```
<img id="imgBox3a" src="#" style="display:none">
<img id="imgBox3b" src="#" style="display:none">
<img id="imgBox3c" src="#" style="display:none">
```

Then onclick call:

```
check_value(1, "3a", "accessories");
check_value(2, "3b", "accessories");
check_value(3, "3c", "accessories");
```

Comment: +1 This answer seems to best fit easily. One question: if the user unchecked the box is there away to make the image disappear as well?

Comment: @charliecodex23 Change el.style.display = ""; to: el.style.display = el.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none'

Comment: Alright, did that but it is now causing interference to the radio buttons

Comment: @charliecodex23 Wrap it in an if (el.type=="checkbox") perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="tire">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="1" onclick='check_value(1, 3, "accesories")'/> Chrome Front Plate<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="2" onclick='check_value(2, 3, "accesories")'/> Jacket<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="3" onclick='check_value(3, 3, "accesories")'/> Gloves            
</form>
<div id='access'></div>    

function check_value(val, id, type) {     
        var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/bike_calculator/images/"+type+val+".jpg";
    alert(img.src)
    var src = document.getElementById("access");
    src.appendChild(img);
      }
```

check this demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u37tN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think appending two images in one image tag isn't possible try this

Create a DIV like this

```
      <div id="image">
     <img id="imgBox3" src="#" style="display:none"/>
       </div>
```

Script:

Create an Image element and append it to the DIV

```
     var imag=document.createElement("img");
     imag.src="image";
     document.getElementById("image").appendChild(imag);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you actually want the checkboxes to act like...well...checkboxes, you should attach your handler to the onchange event:

```
<h2>Choose Accesories</h2>
<form name="tire">
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="1" onchange='check_value(1, 3, "accesories",this)'/> Chrome Front Plate<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="2" onchange='check_value(2, 3, "accesories",this)'/> Jacket<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="field" value="3" onchange='check_value(3, 3, "accesories",this)'/> Gloves            
</form>
```

You'll notice I added another parameter: "this" will point to the element changed.
Then in your function you can do this:

```
function check_value(val, id, type,mycheckbox) {
    if (mycheckbox.checked){
        //do something when it's checked
    }else{
        //do something when it's not checked.
    }
}
```

So how to display multiple images?

One way is to dynamically create images and append them like @Sibu suggested (don't forget to remove them though when they're unchecked).

Another is to have pre-created the image elements with "display:none" (with their src attribute already set) so then the only thing you have to do is play with the display attribute.

Personally I'd say option2 is better, because css changes are faster than dom manipulations.